# Not able to login to ec2 instance from my ubuntu14.04 terminal

Tags: 14.04, ssh

I can loginto the EC2 instance with putty, but with the same .pem file, which i have copied to my ubuntu 14.04 terminal, when trying to connect shows permission denied(public key)
Can any one please help me..

Comment: Copied to where?

Comment: What is the permission of `pem` file?

Answer (score 0):

*Please check **permission of .pem file is it 644** then its ok*

otherwise

**cut the .ssh folder from home user directory for temporary** and then try again

still issue then try with **sudo user**